# Check if array contains an index value in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing, nsarray

I have an array in a plist that contains 2 integer values. I can read the first value no problem by using this code

```
let mdic = dict["m_indices"] as? [[String:Any]]
var mdicp = mdic?[0]["powers"] as? [Any]
self.init(
     power: mdicp?[0] as? Int ?? 0
)
```

Unfortunately, some of the plists do not have a 2nd index value. So calling this

```
power: mdicp?[1] as? Int ?? 0
```

return nil. How can I check whether there is an index there or not so it only grabs values when a value is present? I've attempted to wrap it in an if-let statement

```
        if let mdicp1 = mdic?[0]["powers"] as? [Any]?, !(mdicp1?.isEmpty)! {
        if let mdicp2 = mdicp1?[1] as! Int?, !mdicp2.isEmpty {
            mdicp2 = 1
        }
    } else {
        mdicp2 = 0
    }
```

But my attempts so far have let to multiple console errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're dealing with array of integers and are only worried about the first two items, you can do something like:

```
let items: [Int] = [42, 27]
let firstItem  = items.first ?? 0
let secondItem = items.dropFirst().first ?? 0
```

Whether you really want to use the nil coalescing operator, `??` to make missing values evaluate to `0`, or just leave them as optionals, is up to you.

Or you could do:

```
let firstItem  = array.count > 0 ? array[0] : 0
let secondItem = array.count > 1 ? array[1] : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if mdicp.count > 1,
   let mdicpAtIndex1 = mdicp[1] {
  /// your code
}
```

`mdicp` may contain "n" number of element with optional values, So you have to do optional binding before unwrap it to avoid crash.

For example, if I intialize array with capacity 5

```
var arr = [String?](repeating: nil, count: 5)

print(arr.count)   /// it will print 5
if arr.count > 2 {
      print("yes") /// it will print
}

if arr.count > 2,
   let test = arr[2] { // it won't go inside
    print(test)
}

///if I unwrap it
print(arr[2]!)  /// it will crash
```

Comment: If `mdicp` only has one item, this will crash. Arrays are not like dictionaries that will return `nil` if a key is not found. With array, if the index exceeds the bounds, it will crash.